# Java InterruptedException suspends thread?

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

This should be a simple take for any Java Master. Me being a newbie just wanted to confirm one thing.

I have a class implementing Runnable and like many such classes its run() method has an infinite loop. I want to do some task and then sleep for a min and come back again.

What happens if an Interrupted Exception is encountered while a thread is sleeping?

What I think would happen is the thread being suspended and now the infinite loop is of no help to keep the thread runnning. I'd like to confirm if my understanding is correct or not.

If this is what happens, What would be a possible solution to start up the thread up again.?

Comment: This should help good. If reading is your forte... http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05236/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is mostly correct - When your thread is sleeping , if it gets interrupted , this will cause an `InterruptedException` to be thrown - your code in `run()` will have to catch it and do what it wants to do. The thread itself will not be suspended - because active execution continues on this thread.

You may want to continue the execution of the thread after you handle the `InterruptedException` in your catch block.

Comment: note that InterruptedException is most often used to signal to a thread that it should _stop what it is doing_.  so, catching and ignoring this exception is a good way to have your app hang on shutdown.

Comment: @jtahlborn, you are right about the significance and the treatment following an `InterruptedException` , but the question is not about that.

Comment: the question most certainly is about that.  the OP is asking how to ignore an InteruptedExcepiont.  i'm merely adding the warning that that may not _actually_ be a good thing.

Comment: Well jtahlborn is quite correct in getting my question; since I now know that my thread is not terminating I would want to eat up the InterruptedException. But I saw a whole lot of places where people suggest that IE should not just be eaten up... what is suggested here then?

Comment: If the question is about how to ignore the IE , then I can say that it is not worded clear enough. Notwithstanding that , it remains correct that IE should not be ignored, and that the receiving thread should promptly cleanup and close.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting to use `thread.interrupt()` for inter-thread communication for proper task execution -(this is bad idea - IE is always used to tell the thread to stop ). There are many established idioms for doing this - see `ExecutorService` class in `java.util.concurrent` package for proper task scheduling.

Comment: Alright.. thats more clear now.. thanks Bhaskar...
This raises a second question, in the run() method there is no option but to catch IE and if I don't find any scenario where the thread might be interrupted what do you suggest to do in catch?

Answer (score 6):

Wrong.
An `InterruptedException` would just terminate the `sleep()` call and throw an exception.
As long as you handle the exception appropriately, your thread will continue running.

Comment: And what if I set the status of thread to interrupted by Thread.currentThread().Interrupt();
where I catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

The thread will not be suspended.

If you catch the `InterruptedException`, execution will continue in your exception handler.

If you do not catch the `InterruptedException`, the thread will terminate.

Comment: Inside a `run()` method - there is no choice but to catch the IE - this is a checked exception and you cannot put it into `throws` clause. At other places where you can do this , yes you may just let it bubble up.

Comment: @Bhaskar: true, you'd have to catch it and wrap it in an unchecked exception to get it all the way up.

Answer (score 0):

InterruptedExceptions don't just happen. Some exceptions, like IOExceptions, happen unpredictably due to inherent flakiness of the medium, but that is not the case for interruptions.

Interruption is a deliberate signal to a thread, usually sent by the application while it is shutting down, that it should finish up what it's doing and stop running. If the thread getting interrupted happens to be waiting or sleeping at the time, then the thread gets woken up and an InterruptedException gets thrown from the wait or sleep method.

Useful libraries like java.util.concurrent and guava use interrupts for thread cancellation. If you try to use them for something else then you can't use those libraries.